# How to perform an upsert on entity with JoinColumn in JPA and Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

Fairly new to the hibernate-core integrate with JPA. Our entities look like

```
@MappedSuperclass
abstract class BasicEntity {

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name="uuid",strategy="uuid")
    @GeneratedValue(generator="uuid")
    private String id;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
class Book extends BasicEntity { 
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="book_genre")
    Genre genre

    @Column(name="texture")
    String texture;
}

@Data //lombok
@Entity
@Table(name="user_book_mapping")
class UserBookMapping extends BasicEntity {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "book_id")
    private Book book;
    
    @Column(name="user_id")
    String user_id;
}
```

What I am trying to perform is for every book read by a user, **`upsert`**(a book can be read twice by the same user) the `UserBookMapping` table. Request object includes an array of user and books `[{userId, bookId}]` attributes for me to process.

Currently I am stuck with a solution where I am ending up fetching the `Book` entity from the primary table first, then fetching if such a row already exists with a combination of `userId+bookId` and then creating a new instance of `UserBookMapping` to write it to the database.

This doesn't look optimized in any sense to me. Theoretically(and in the NoSql world), what should be sufficient for me to do all of this would be to ensure valid `bookIds` are requested (`EXISTS`) and then perform an `UPSERT` for the `UserBookMapping`. But I am puzzled with both the ways to write and to formulate the data as java objects while computing.

Q1. Do I really need to construct the `Book` entity?

Q2. What is the clean way to do what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: Could you please clarify the desired effect? Which data entity do you want to get upserted, the `Book`?

Comment: If you're only dealing with existing `Book`s and merely wish to establish the association between `Book` and `UserBookMapping`, you can simply use `entityManager.getReference()`. No need to actually fetch the `Book` entity

Comment: @crizzis Thank you for the response. I am trying to upsert the `UserBookMapping`, could you elaborate on the `entityManager.getReference` aspect?

Answer (score 1):

As was suggested by @crizzis, you can do something like this:

```java
Book book = entityManager.getReference(Book.class, bookId);
Long booksPerUserCount = entityManager.createQuery(
    "select count(bu) from UserBookMapping bu where bu.book = :book and bu.user_id = :userId",
 Long.class )
.setParameter("book", book)
.setParameter("userId", userId)
.getSingleResult(); 

if (booksPerUserCount == 0) {
   UserBookMapping userBook = new UserBookMapping();
   userBook.setBook(book);
   userBook.setUserId(userId);
   entityManager.persist(userBook);
}
```

But it will work only if you know for sure that a book with id `bookId` exists.
You can read about `entityManager.getReference()` in [hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-get-reference).

Please also note that you should use `@Data` lombok annotation with caution in hibernate/jpa entity, see for example [this article](https://deinum.biz/2019-02-13-Lombok-Data-Ojects-Arent-Entities/).